# How to git ignore folders that begin with # sign

Tags: git, gitignore

Is it possible to create a `.gitignore` file, that ignores files or folders that begin with `#`?

**Example:**

```
#DATABASE_FILES
#DOCUMENTATION
```

Comment: `\#DATABASE_FILES` maybe. Try it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As the [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore#_pattern_format) specifies:

> A line starting with `#` serves as a comment. **Put a backslash** (`\`) **in front of the first hash** for patterns that begin with a hash.

(added formatting)

So you can use:

```
\#DATABASE_FILES
\#DOCUMENTATION
```

To escape the hash.

Escaping (putting a `\` in front of a character) is by the way a common technique used in the *nix world (only a hint for equivalent problems).